# Debian system: install specific packages from source automatically to boost the performance

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

On Debian /Ubuntu systems, how to set a list of packages which can be installed from sources automatically by apt-get or aptitude? The server is mainly for scientific computing and I would like to compile some specific packages with highly optimized flags such as `-O3 -march=native` to boost the performance. I know how to do this for one single package, however, I don't want to redo these when there comes an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Debian's [apt-build](https://packages.debian.org/apt-build) package.

Comment: I can't find how to use to build new releases automatically..

Comment: If you look at the `apt-build(1)` man page, you see there commands like `apt-build update` (Retrieve new lists of packages), `apt-build upgrade` (Perform an upgrade) and `apt-build install` (Build and install new packages). Put a sane combination of these into a cron job and most of it should be done.